# For loop continue

Tags: scala, for-loop

Consider the following loop that represents a "neighborhood"

```
for(x <- -1 to 1; y <- -1 to 1)
{
   // If we are in the current field, just get the one above
   if((x == 0) && (y == 0)) y = 1 // Problem: Reassignment to val
}
```

as you can see, I'd get a reassignment to val compilation error. In Java I would do "continue" to skip that.

What would be an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a guard:

```
for (x <- -1 to 1; y <- -1 to 1; if !(x == 0 && y == 0)) {
    ...
}
```

Alternately:

```
for (x <- -1 to 1; y <- -1 to 1 by (if (x == 0) 2 else 1)) {
    ...
}
```

I think the first one is more readable, though.